# Piecewise monotonicity of real analytic functions

Tags: real-analysis

This may have a completely trivial answer, but I don't see it at the moment:

If the series expansion $f(x)=\sum_n a_n x^n$ is valid on the whole of $\mathbb{R}$, must there exist a countably infinite partition
$$\ldots r_{-2} < r_{-1} < r_0 < r_1 < r_2\ldots$$
of the real line such that $f$ is monotone on each part $[r_i, r_{i+1}]$, $i\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: the answer to the problem linked to in the above comment does not study in the detail the structure of the set of open intervals on which $f$ is monotone. In particular it is not clear (to me) if the endpoints of these intervals would satisfy the condition $\ldots r_{-2} < r_{-1} < r_0 < r_1 < r_2\ldots$. (Perhaps the set of endpoints could have a limit point in $\mathbb R$?) @DavidMitra

Comment: Sorry, misread your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The zero set of a real-analytic function is discrete (because near any zero $x^*$, it can be written as $(x-x^*)^n g(x)$ with $g(x^*)\ne 0$).
2. The derivative of a real-analytic  function is also real-analytic.

Put the above together to conclude that the set of critical points of $f$ is discrete, proving the claim.

---

You don't need to assume that $f$ is represented by one power series on the entire line. Real analyticity only requires local representation. For example, $f(x)=1/(1+x^2)$ is real analytic on $\mathbb{R}$ but is not the sum of a globally convergent power series.